# No callback when using firebase Facebook login

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I am trying to use firebase Authentication to allow login using facebook login. Everything works as expected up to the part when I should be getting the callback after a successfully login.

I am using the latest Facebook and Firebase SDKs:

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.0.0'
```

I have added my `LoginButton` inside my `Fragment`, that I will be using Data binding.

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
        name="vm"
        type="my.app.app.ui.ViewModel" />
    </data>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ui.auth.SignUpFragment">

        <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
            xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/facebook_sign_up_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Inside my Fragment, up to here, everything is working the way it should:

```
class SignUpFragment : Fragment()
    lateinit var binding: FragmentSignUpBinding
    private val factory: ViewModelFactory  by instance()
    private var callbackManager: CallbackManager? = null
    lateinit var mainView: View
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth


    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,R.layout.fragment_sign_up, container, false)
        val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get(ViewModel::class.java)
        mainView = binding.root
        binding.vm = viewModel
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create()

        binding.facebookSignUpButton.setPermissions("email", "public_profile")
        binding.facebookSignUpButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
        override fun onSuccess(loginResult: LoginResult) {
            Log.d("FacebookActivity", "onSuccess")
            handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.accessToken)
        }

        override fun onCancel() {
            Log.d("FacebookActivity", "facebook:onCancel")
        }

        override fun onError(error: FacebookException) {
            Log.d("FacebookActivity", "facebook:onError", error)
        }
        })
        return mainView
    }


    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        callbackManager?.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }
}
```

I am able to use the facebook login, and I can see that the app was added  in the Apps & Websites on facebook.com.

But I never get a callback. Not from my `onSuccess`, `onCancel` or `onError`

I don't get an error, I just don't get the callback. Has anyone ever encountered this problem? I am also using Google login and I am not experiencing any problems from that login type.

Comment: Can you please provide the code for the whole Fragment?

Comment: I've added the rest, which wasn't that much, but hopefully this will give a more complete idea of what is happening.

Comment: So, when you tap on the button, the facebook login page appears and after typing the credentials facebook login page closes but you don't get a callback. Is it right?

Comment: That is correct. I managed to have it work by using the Facebook Custom activity, but not using the modal.